# How to sort the Schemas on Swagger-ui SpringDoc open ui

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

I want to sort my `Schemas` generated for my Entity classes, DTO classes in `Springdoc UI`.
I am able to sort the `tags` and `operations` using the below configuration in `yml` file but my schemas are not in the sorted order.

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    tags-sorter: alpha
    operations-sorter: alpha
    doc-expansion: none
```

How could I sort my schemas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have full control of the schemas order using OpenApiCustomiser.
This is a sample code that you can customize using Comparators, depending on the sorting logic you want:

```java
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser sortSchemasAlphabetically() {
    return openApi -> {
        Map<String, Schema> schemas = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
        openApi.getComponents().setSchemas(new TreeMap<>(schemas));
    };
}
```

If you are interested on the sorting on the swagger-ui, not on the server side, then you can log a feature request on the swagger-ui project.

Comment: The [property](https://springdoc.org/properties.html) is `springdoc: writer-with-order-by-keys: true`.